# Sympy check satisfiability of statement involving symbols

Tags: sympy

I have a program that generates logical statements involving symbols, like `conds` below

```
import sympy
x, y = sympy.symbols('x,y')
conds = sympy.Eq(x+y,-1) & (x>1) & (y>2)
```

I would like to check if they're satisfiable (if there exist `x,y` meeting the conditions). In general, how can I reduce logical statements involving symbols?

`sympy.solve([sympy.Eq(x+y,1), x>1, y>2])` gives a NotImplementedError and the inequality solvers can only handle one variable IIRC.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly when this will or won't work (the problem is undecidable in full generality) but SymPy has a function `reduce_inequalities` that does work for the example shown:

```
In [8]: reduce_inequalities(conds)
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: woah thanks, the examples at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html don't mention multiple variables at all so I thought that functionality didn't exist

Comment: update: no this gives false even for true statements: `sympy.reduce_inequalities((x > 0) & sympy.Eq(x,3))`

Comment: Make sure you are using the most recent version of SymPy. `reduce_inequalities([(x > 0) , sympy.Eq(x,3)]) -> `Eq(x, 3)`.

Comment: I think it is a bug that it gives False when using `&`.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23953

Comment: Note that `simplify` works for the case where `reduce_inequalities` is currently broken.

Answer (score 0):

A new addition to SymPy is the simplex solver. You can pass this equation list to `lpmin` with an objective of 0 to see if the system is feasible or not:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> lpmin(0,(Eq(x+y,1), x>=1, y>=2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
sympy.solvers.simplex.InfeasibleLPError:
The constraint set is empty!

# change Eq rhs from 1 to 3

>>> lpmin(0,(Eq(x+y,3), x>=1, y>=2))
(0, {x: 1, y: 2})
```

The first case is infeasible and the second is feasible (and a solution is offered). You must replace `<` and `>` with their non-strict counterparts.